# retrieving data with mongoose and putting it into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This returns undefined. How can I put what retrieve in an array?

```
    function getUsers(place) {

    if (place === 'France') {

        myModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
            var array = [];
            for (var i in result) {
                array.push(result[i]);
            }
            return result;
        });
    }}
```

Comment: Hi, You can use promises to return the array values or add observer to update values when your array is built

Answer (score 0):

Check result is it empty or not and return array insteat of result

```
function getUsers(place) {

if (place === 'France') {

    myModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        let array = [];
        if (result){
        for (var i in result) {
            array.push(result[i]);
        }
        return array;
        } else{
        return "No data found"
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: I had to return the promise and work on the result using .then() method. I couldn't get the array out of the promise because it would become undefined. And IDK if my method is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop through the result object. Do this instead:

```
function getUsers(place) {
    if (place === 'France') {
        myModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
            if(result && result.length)
              return result;
            console.log(err)
        });
    }}
```

Comment: I had to return the promise and work on the result using .then() method. I couldn't get the array out of the promise because it would become undefined.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Can you post the snippet and the promise object that you are getting?